# How to format an array with random numbers that has more than 1 indexes of 0 Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make displayArray look like an array, but I can't figure it out.
It prints out this:

```
[7, 8, 9 , 0, 9, 0, ]
```

Instead of this:

```
[7, 8, 9, 0, 9, 0]
```

I know that the problem is because of

```
System.out.print(b + ", ");
```

but I don't know what else to do.

```
import java.util.*;
public class changeUp 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] arr = new int[6]; 
        populateArray(arr);
        displayArray(arr);
    }
    private static void populateArray(int[] arr)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            int ranInd = r.nextInt(6);
            System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
            arr[ranInd] = console.nextInt();
        }
    }
    private static void displayArray(int[] arr)
    {
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int b : arr)
        {
            System.out.print(b + ",  ");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You print `", "` on the last iteration of `displayArray()` `for` loop.

To avoid this add index check:

```
private static void displayArray(int[] arr)
{
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        int b = arr[i];
        System.out.print(b);

        if(i < arr.length - 1) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a value: 4
Enter a value: 4
Enter a value: 4
Enter a value: 4
Enter a value: 4
Enter a value: 4
[4, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4]
```